# Create raphael element in one setTimeout, remove it in another setTimeout

Tags: raphael, settimeout, jquery

I'm trying to create an animation where I create 4 circles in Raphael 10 seconds after the page is loaded. Then, 10 seconds later, I want to remove all of these circles, and make 10 more (10 new circles with names that are different than the original 10).

This is what I have:

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 100, 1350, 800);

setTimeout(function() {
    var a1 = paper.circle(200,200,100);
    var a2 = paper.circle(300,300,100);
    var a3 = paper.circle(400,400,100);
    var a4 = paper.circle(500,500,100);
}, 10000);

setTimeout(function() {
    a1.remove();
    a2.remove();
    a3.remove();
    a4.remove();

    var b1 = paper.circle(300,200,100);
    var b2 = paper.circle(400,300,100);
    var b3 = paper.circle(500,400,100);
    var b4 = paper.circle(600,500,100);
}, 20000);
```

However, when I get to the send setTimeout, the `.remove()`'s don't do anything. They kill the rest of the script. When I take them out, the new circles create just fine, but I can't get rid of the first set.

I understand this is something with the bindings, but I can't get it to work. I tried doing this in the first setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var a1 = paper.circle(200,200,100);
    $(a1.node).live();
    var a2 = paper.circle(300,300,100);
    $(a2.node).live();
    var a3 = paper.circle(400,400,100);
    $(a3.node).live();
    var a4 = paper.circle(500,500,100);
    $(a4.node).live();
}, 1000);
```

But when it gets to the first `.live()` it dies.

Any advice? I feel like there is something very basic that I'm missing. Maybe some behind the scenes explanation as to what it's trying to do?

I will be expanding this to almost 100 frames (100 setTimeouts). Any advice on how to make this more efficient? I'm a bit new to this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the circles were declared inside the anonymous function passed to the first setTimeout. If you remove the `var` from the variable declarations, they will be global, and your code should work.

By global I mean they will belong to `window`. You can reference them as `window.varname`, or just `varname` (if there is no other `var varname` in the same scope where you are trying to reference `varname`).